# how to implement an early return (or override return) with void Method rather bool()

Tags: c#, design-patterns, overriding, new-operator

i was trying to do something like the code below to avoid using a `Boolean` return type method, and i couldn't find any way to implement it correctly:

```
public void myMethod(int someInitializingParameter)
{
                                              //return (kinda override operator)
     if(TargetObjToinitItsProperties == null) MsgDbgWinShow("Error: Line#637-xxx.CS", "Property was accessed prior to parent object init");
     TargetObjToInitItsProperties.IntProp1 = someInitializingParameter;
}

static void MsgDbgWinShow(string Wtitle, string Wmsg)
{
   create a window (windowsTitle=Wtitle .. size width ...create TextBlock.Content= Wmsg...etc')

   CreatedWindow.Show();
//here is self exit and return ...from self but will not act as return operator...
}
```

**is there any approach to use void as return type rather using a Type?**

Comment: what's wrong with `return;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply throw an exception and catch it in the caller.
That leaves the method at the point you put the 'throw':

```
    public void myMethod(int someInitializingParameter)
    {
        //return (kinda override operator)
        if(TargetObjToinitItsProperties == null)
            throw new Exception("Property was accessed prior to parent object init");

        TargetObjToInitItsProperties.IntProp1 = someInitializingParameter;
    }
```

You could even create your own type of exception, when you inherit from it. Then you can put in some extra data:

```
class MyException : Exception
{
    // some enhancements
    public string ExtraData;

    public MyException(string sMessage, string sExtraData)
        : base(sMessage)
    {
        ExtraData = sExtraData;
    }
}
```

Now you can throw it:

```
    public void myMethod(int someInitializingParameter)
    {
        //return (kinda override operator)
        string sExtraData = "Hallo";
        if (TargetObjToinitItsProperties == null)
            throw new MyException("Property was accessed prior to parent object init",
                                  sExtraData);

        TargetObjToInitItsProperties.IntProp1 = someInitializingParameter;
    }
```

And in the caller you can catch it and use the extra data:

```
    public void CallingMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            myMethod(23);
        }
        catch (MyException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + e.ExtraData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: that's sounds like a real good alternative in a field i haven't tried yet, only(on second thought) wouldnt it be expensive using `Exception` rather a simple method, or the cost of window i open is not less expensive ?

Comment: or am i miss-mixing `try catch` with Exception (i have read that Exception handeling is expensive or only try catch is...)

Comment: No problem, exceptions are not expensive. And if you want to show a message box, i would do that in the caller where you catch it.

Comment: I use exceptions for years and where ever i can. And i even had never to think about it belonging to performance. By the way, exception are the build in standart way for this in all .net classes.

Comment: and in my method, i could prefix the design when not in coding-debug mode  the parent method will choose between "Msgbxwindow" and log into file...

Comment: @DieterMeemken While the use of `Exception` in this case is perfectly normal (assuming `TargetObjToinitItsProperties` should never be `null`, hence an exception), your statement about throwing an exceptions are  not expensive and *should* be use where ever you can is kindda misleading... see here [Improving Managed Code Performance: Exception Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms998547.aspx#scalenetchapt05_topic24) in Microsoft Patterns and Practices library on MSDN

Comment: @Dieter MeemKen , i am trying your suggestion, though i couldnt call a method to invoke from it `ExcepM : Exception { myMethodThatshowsOrLogs(); }`

Comment: sorry i forgot the constructor (:

Comment: @IronGeek Good hint. My point was, that while building 'normal' applications you don't have to worry about that. Thince exceptions should be used for somewhat exceptional application states and not for 'normal control flow' they even should appear only very seldom.